# PHP: Remove Rows Not in Large List

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api, temp-tables

My application needs to change a value in a table if it is **not** in a very large set (20,000 items) that come in through an XML API.  Obviously, it would be easy to create a solution that would be very slow.

I'd like to know how you might recommend doing this?  I'm thinking adding the unique IDs of the items in the XML to a temporary table, then executing a single query:

```
UPDATE item SET status = "deleted" WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM keep_items);
```

What do you think?

Comment: You could, of course, build some sort of trees (or other suitable datastructures) in PHP itself but I don't think that this would be faster than your approach (since mysql (etc) are highly optimized). Best to run a benchmark I guess.

Comment: I would do the opposite: first run:
`select id from keep_deals` and only if it doesn't return empty - run the `delete`

Comment: Good idea, @alfasin, but unfortunately, the item may already be in the database.  The `keep_deals` table is the temporary table I would hypothetically create.

Comment: I don't understand... if the item is already IN the DB then by running: `select 1 from __table_name where id = ?` should return `1` - then you don't delete. If it returns an empty resultset - delete.

Comment: @alfasin It's the other way around.  I don't want to check if it's in the database, I want to check if it's in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution I presented, which was to create and populate a temporary table while the data was being read, and then ran:

```
DELETE FROM item WHERE item.id NOT IN (SELECT temp_item.id FROM temp_item);
```

The result is very fast.